# How can I replace this price slider with a simple HTML select in this PHP page? Can the select option pass 2 values (min and max price)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xhtml

I am pretty new in PHP and I am absolutly not into front end (I am more a Java backend guy) and I have the following problem (I think pretty simple to someone having some PHP\frontend background).

I am working on a very old style PHP web application.

Into a page I have a form containing a price slector through which the user can choose a price range for a searchedproduct (something like **from 50$ to 100$**). Using the selector the use chose the min prince and the max prince in the range. For the slider it is using this JavaScript library: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

This is the price range slider into the PHP code of my search page:

```
<div class="nouislider-wrapper">
    <div class="nouislider" data-min="0" data-max="<?php echo $max_price; ?>" data-start="<?php echo "[".$price_min.",".$price_max."]"; ?>" data-step="10" data-direction="<?php echo RTL_DIR; ?>" data-input="price_range"></div>
    <?php echo $texts['PRICE']." / ".$texts['NIGHT']; ?> : <?php echo CURRENCY_SIGN; ?> <input type="text" name="price_range" class="slider-target" id="price_range" value="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Ok, from what I have understood it simply put the min price into a **$price_min** and the max price into the **$price_max**.

I need to remove the previous slider and replace it with a simple dropdown menu, something like a simple HTML **select** tag, something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="XXX">50$-100$</option>
    <option value="YYY">100$-150$</option>
    <option value="ZZZ">150$-200$</option>
    <option value="WWW">200$+</option>
</select>
```

My problem is: how can I pass the 2 values (for example 50 and 100) when an user select a voice from this select tab? Is it possible pass the 2 values (**$price_min** and **$price_max**) into an **option** element of a **select** tag?

If it is possible I prefear don't change logici (passing other values) because it is a very legacy application and it could be complicated handle the changes it the backend that uses these values, so if I can do it in the select it's better.

What do you think about it?

Comment: now which values is passing min or max ? i mean which value you need  min or max from options or both?

Comment: @AhmedGinani now it is passing both. These value will be used by a backend query to search products in the price range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not pass both value separately in selecttag but you can do it like

```
<select name="range">
    <option value="<?php echo $price_min.'-'.$max_price; ?>"><?php echo $price_min.'$-'.$max_price.'$'; ?></option>
</select>
```

now you have to do some stuff in php side

```
<?php
// suppose you select 50$-100$ you get 50-100 in $range 
$range = $_POST['range'];
$values = explode("-",$range);
$min_value = $values[0]
$max_value = $values[1] 
?>
```